# Sqlite Delete Query syntax in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to write a Query to delete a row from the table. I am confused of writing the statement. I need some help in writing this. I am providing my requirement here with plain sql statement.

(Pseudo code)

```
delete from tablename where value =="string1" && value2 == "string2" && value3 == "string3";
```

I want to write this in the Sqlite syntax for android `db.delete(tablename, whereclause, whereargs);`.

I would be thankful for your help.

Answer (score 28):

a better way would be to use

```
String where = "value1 = ?"
+ " AND value2 = ?"
+ " AND value3 = ?";
String[] whereArgs = {string1,string2,string3};
```

Answer (score 16):

```
String table_name = "myTable";
String where = "value1 = 'string1'"
    + " AND value2 = 'string2'"
    + " AND value3 = 'string3'";
String whereArgs = null;
mDb.delete(table_name, where, whereArgs);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am going to use it. I have another question that what if I want to provide the integer. shall I directly place the integer variable directly into 'string2' position.

Comment: If "value2" is integer then you can write "value2 = 1". If "value2" is TEXT then you must write "value2 = '1'"

Answer (score 2):

```
mdb.delete("tablename",new String("value1=? and Value2=? and value3=?"),new String[]{value1,value2,value3});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM tablename WHERE value1='"+string1+"' AND value2='"+string2+"' AND value3='"+string3+"' "); //delete  row in a table with the condition
db.close();
```