# Removing a row from database in SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new to SQLite Database and Android Application. I want to delete the specific record when the user enters a name and clicks on the 'Remove Account' Button.

I have the following codes but I can't seem to achieve what I want. Do you have any insight on what may be wrong with my code?

In `mydbadapter.java`

```
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "customer.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "customerAcc";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private SQLiteDatabase _db;
    private final Context context;

    public static final String name = "_name";
    public static final int COLUMN_NAME_ID = 0;
    public static final String password = "_password";
    public static final int COLUMN_PW_ID = 1;
    public static final String address = "_address";
    public static final int COLUMN_ADDRESS_ID = 2;
    public static final String phoneNumber = "_phoneNumber";
    public static final int COLUMN_PHONE_ID = 3;


    protected static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " " + "(" + name + " Text not null, " + password + " Text not null, "
            + address + " Text not null, " + phoneNumber + " text not null);";

    private String MYDBADAPTER_LOG_CAT = "MY_LOG";

    private MyDBOpenHelper dbHelper;

    public MyDbAdapter(Context _context)
    {
        this.context = _context;

        dbHelper = new MyDBOpenHelper (context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void close()
    {
        _db.close();
        Log.w(MYDBADAPTER_LOG_CAT, "DB Closed");
    }

    public void open() throws SQLiteException
    {
        try
        {
            _db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            Log.w(MYDBADAPTER_LOG_CAT, "DB opened as writable database");
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e)
        {
            _db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Log.w(MYDBADAPTER_LOG_CAT, "DB opened as readable database");
        }
    }

    public long insertEntry(String cname, String cpassword, String caddress, String cphone)
    {   
        // create codes go here
    }

    public boolean removeEntry(String custname)
    {
        try
        {
        _db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        return _db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, name + "=" + custname, null)>0;
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean updateEntry(long _rowIndex, String entryName, String entryTel)
    {
        //update codes are here
    }

    public Cursor retrieveAllEntriesCursor()
    {
        //retrieve codes are here
    }

    public class MyDBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        public MyDBOpenHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version)
        {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            Log.w(MYDBADAPTER_LOG_CAT, "Helper : DB " + DATABASE_TABLE + " Created!!");
        }


    } // End of myDBOpenHelper

}// End of myDBAdapter
```

In `MainActivity.java`

```
btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String custname = etRName.getText().toString();

            myDB.removeEntry(custname);
        }       
    });
```

My code doesn't give me any errors but when I click on the 'Remove Account' button the record is still there.

Comment: Can you post the crashlog from logcat ?

Comment: Show me your DBHelper or Database class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works, although I would recommend

```
db.delete(TABLE, "column_name=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(custname) });
```

or use

```
String query = "DELETE FROM " +TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE "  + COLUM_NAME+ " = " + "'"+VALUE +"'" ;
db.execSQL(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

public boolean removeEntry(String custname)
    {

bolean returnBoolean;

try
    {

```
 db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "column_name=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(custname)});
 returnBoolean= true;
```

}

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    returnBoolean= false;
    e.printStackTrace();
}

finally
{
    db.close();
}
```

return returnBoolean;
}

Answer (score 0):

There seems some problem with your query syntax. Here's a line from my code, it works for me

```
db.delete(Table_name, KEY_COLUMN + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(custname)});
```

you're not getting the structure of query. Second parameter is for **where** clause of the query. See the first answer of [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095309/sqlite-delete-query-syntax-in-android) post, to better understand the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest taking a look at [cupboard](http://code.neenbedankt.com/introducing-cupboard-simple-persistance-for-android/), your code here will be greatly reduced / simplified and it makes this kind of work so much more readable / understandable :)