# Using AND and OR in WHERE clause of SQLite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to **delete** a record from table in `SQLite` Android by using **AND and OR**.
My primitive statement looks like this.

```
public void deleteUser(user usr) 
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_USER_DETAILS, KEY_FNAME + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(usr.getLName()) });
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: So , are you getting any error ?

Comment: I Ain't getting any errors its working fine but,i need to filter the records

Comment: `AND` and  `OR` what? You need to give more information.

Comment: in AND , what other parameter you want to add  ?

Comment: For example delete from userdetails where fname=xyz and lname=abc

Comment: Please refer to this  [Link][1] it is more clear with delete query 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095309/sqlite-delete-query-syntax-in-android

Comment: I don't understand your question. you want to use `AND and OR`. fine. just do it. are you actually stuck at some point?

Comment: strange that your column name constant is `KEY_FNAME` but your model getter is `getLName`.

Comment: @njzk2 that's a typo mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your naming conventions are consistent, you probably want something like this:

```
db.delete(TABLE_USER_DETAILS, KEY_FNAME + " = ? AND " + KEY_LNAME + " = ?", 
    new String[] { String.valueOf(usr.getFName()), String.valueOf(usr.getLName()) });
```

If the `usr.getFName()` and `usr.getLName()` methods return `String`s, you can get rid of the `String.valueOf()` around each.